# ssl svn user login problem

Tags: svn, apache, ssl

I've a subversion server, on Apache (on WindowsXP), which is accessible over the net using http. I wanted to use ssl/https to access it. I haven't messed around with forcing http -> https yet, and can login using http:// fine. However, if I use https://, the login fails, and I get an "Authentication required!" 401 error message.

I guess it's a configuration issue on my server(?), but haven't found a solution yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably better to ask over at serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic HTTP setup, you will have to configure ssl certificates / authorization for secure HTTP.

See the following for setup:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51753
- http://wiki.freaks-unidos.net/Apache2%20SSL%20and%20Subversion%20in%20Debian

Comment: I have set up certs etc. but have obviously missed something.

Comment: @debs: Ubantu instruction setup has worked for me. Can you just go through that to see what is it that you have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I've made several changes, and it's now working. Unfortunately I can't pinpoint why, but thanks for the help anyway.